# How to combine and get data from multiple tables for a single id

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-queryset

table A :

```
................
id   name  age |
................
1    G     29  |
2    A     30  |
................
```

table B : (table b have the foreign key of table A in tableA_id field which comes multiple)

```
id   phone     rank   tableA_id
1    98989     A      1
2    98989     C      1
3    98989     D      2
```

table C : (table C have the foreign key of table A in tableA_id field which comes multiple)

```
id   notes     email            tableA_id
1    98989     A@gmail.com      1
2    98989     C@gmail.com      1
```

In my case i am want to get all the data from all the tables and want to display in a single page . the what i want is i want one single query to get the all data from all of 
    three table with one query set.
    And id what i am sending is Table_id = 1
    so how can i get the data for table 1 from all the tables can anyone have idea please  let me now i am a new be here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, probably you can't do it in single query. But using [**`prefetch_related`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) you can load all the related tables, so that DB hits will be reduced. For example:

```
# if the models are defined like this:

class TableA(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    age = models.IntegerField(...)

class TableB(models.Model):
    table_a = models.ForeignKey(TableA)


class TableC(models.Model):
    table_a = models.ForeignKey(TableA)

# then the query will be like this

table_data = TableA.objects.filter(pk=1).prefetch_related('tableb', 'tablec')
for data in table_data:
    print(data.name)
    print(data.tableb.all().values())
    print(data.tablec.all().values())
```